# Ignore lighting in A-Frame imported glTF model similarly to blender

Tags: aframe

I have a model that uses a texture atlas .png as the texture for a material for a low poly model with about 4 colors. I am using Blender 2.81 and exporting as glTF.

[Blender shaders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyNxE.png)

When I import it in A-Frame, it comes in as untextured and white.

[A-Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnAth.png)

I can add a BSDF shader and the texture applies properly, but now due to the BSDF it has these lightings and all of the faces are different colors now.

[BSDF shader model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh2Pn.png)

In Unity and Godot you can set things to be "unlit" to keep the flat colors.

I tried the solution here:

[AFrame: how to use flat shading on a mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299870/aframe-how-to-use-flat-shading-on-a-mesh)

But it results in colors not quite the same as  the texture atlas.

[With "unlit"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6X8F.png)

[The colors in my color palette/atlas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YUZh.png)

Also, there's a 3js example that baked in lighting and textures. This soft shading is what I'm trying to replicate.

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_animation_keyframes

Is it possible is A-Frame to get the true unlit color from the texture?

Answer (score 0):

Found an ok solution: you can set the scene renderer's colorManagement to true along with the unlit script from the linked SO link.

[Flat chi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PawZ8.png)

https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/renderer.html