# gltf animations are not playing with flat shader

Tags: shader, aframe, gltf

I am using A-Frame 1.2.0. I have a gltf model on scene and I want to add flat shader this model.

```
 <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"gltf-model="dracoDecoderPath: js/draco/; "renderer="colorManagement: true; alpha: true;">
      <a-entity id="camera-rig">
                <a-camera id="camera" position="0 1.65 0" pivot="0 0 0" cursor="fuse:false;"></a-camera>
      </a-entity>
      <a-assets timeout="10000">
                <a-asset-item id="CesiumMan" src="assets/models/CesiumMan.gltf" response-type="arraybuffer"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      <a-gltf-model src="#CesiumMan" flat-shader="true" position='0 0 0' animation-mixer="clip:*"></a-gltf-model>
</a-scene>
```

And my flat shader code is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56299870/aframe-how-to-use-flat-shading-on-a-mesh)

```
const FlatShader = {
    schema: {default: true} ,

  init() {
    this.el.addEventListener('object3dset', this.update.bind(this));
  },//init

  update() {
    const mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
    const { data } = this;
    if (!mesh) {
      return;
    }
    mesh.traverse(function(node) {
      if (node.isMesh && data) {
        const mat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
        node.material = mat1;
        node.material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });

  },//update

}; // FlatShader

export default FlatShader
```

Flat shader is working but after added flat shader, model animations are not working. Model stays in its static pose.

Any ideas what could be causing the problem ? I may be missing something, but i have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `a-frame`s version of threejs (modified 125) , You need to "tell" the material, that your model utilizes "skinning" for animations:

```
 material.skinning = true;
```

Since three r.129 [this is no longer necessary](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide#128--129)

---

So, all you need is to change the Materials `skinning` property to **true**:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/donmccurdy/aframe-extras@v6.1.1/dist/aframe-extras.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      // wait for the model to load
      this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", evt => {
        // create new material - with it skinning flag raised
        const new_material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial({skinning: true});
        const mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');

        // traverse the mesh and apply the material
        mesh.traverse(node => {
          if (!node.isMesh) return;
          node.material = new_material;
          node.material.needsUpdate = true;
        })
      })
    }
  })

</script>
<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="model" src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/20656ea38ce797a8dff0d2915b656aff75d32a71/2.0/CesiumMan/glTF-Binary/CesiumMan.glb"></a-asset-item>
  </a-assets>
    <a-entity position="1 0 -3" gltf-model="#model" animation-mixer="clip: *" foo></a-entity>
  <a-entity position="-1 0 -3" gltf-model="#model" animation-mixer="clip: *"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Cesium man model is from the [Kronos Group glTF sample models repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/tree/master/2.0/CesiumMan)